# A simple mail program works if hardcoded but throws exception if used in form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this simple code which works for me if i hardcode all the requirements i.e. send/receipent email address etc. but throws exception for if used in  Form:

```
mail.From = new MailAddress(fromtext);
```

> throws ArgumentException was unhandled
>                    The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.
>                     Parameter name: address

Complete Code:

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        string FromPass ="******" ;
        string fromtext=FromText.Text;
        string totext = ToText.Text;
        string subject = SubjectText.Text;
        string Message = MessageBody.Text;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(fromtext);  //exception
        mail.To.Add(totext);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = Message;

        /* if (fD.FileName != string.Empty)
         {
             Attachment attachment;
             attachment = new Attachment(fD.FileName);
             mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
         }*/
        SmtpServer.Timeout = 10000;
        SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromtext, FromPass);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

    }
```

Any Suggestions !!!!

Comment: what do you mean *if used in form*. What is the error you get?

Comment: put a break point and see what is the value you get in `FromText.Text`

Comment: to me, it seems that you're not checking if the textbox has been filled. could i also ask why this was placed in the form_Load event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have placed this code into your `Form1_Load` Event, as this does not allow the user to enter any data into the `form`.

What I think you mean to do, is have a `submitButton` `onclick` event where you can then check:

```
if (fromText.Text !="" && ToText.Text !="" &&...)
{
 //call a method here to send message, including adding it to body/etc.
 //you may want to do further validation checks here too!
}
else
{
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter all details","Some credentials Missing");
}
```

---

In future, I think you may also benefit from inserting a breakpoint (press `F9`) to then step slowly through your code (line by line) to see where any errors occur. But in this example, you have just placed your code in the form1_load event (which executes when the form loads, and not after user input).

Comment: For a newbie like me,can you tell me an instance when we have to code in Form1_Load or simply it loads?

Comment: you would use it, say, when you were going to import data/set sizes programatically/set locations relevant to screen size/etc. there's quite a few times when it gets used, as it performs its actions **before** the form is rendered. (btw, the best way to say thanks is by pressing the tick on the right ;P , as it says my answer was correct )

Comment: any other problems/ small questions questions you can get me on my profile, or post another question sure :)

Comment: @MrCoder - Hmmmm, for me the tick is always on the left!! :P

Comment: @ChrisDunaway sorry have a different layout of SO than others. (almost mirrored layout) :S

Comment: You can't simply catch someone in private message here at SO- really disgusting :-(

Comment: you might just have to get your rep up a bit more - that way you can create a chatroom :)